# How to show only the first row of a post?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay guys, the code below works fine. Except that since I have given users up to 4 image downloads, the product preview page should only display 1 of the images like the first one in the array in the product page but it shows all rows if the user uploads like 4 images. how can I limit this? thanks.

```
<?php           
        echo 'Your posts:' . '<br>' . '<hr>'; 

        $posts = "SELECT * FROM posts,image_data WHERE userid='$user' AND user_posts.userid = image_data.client_id ORDER BY date_created ASC";
        $posts_result = $mysqli->query($posts);     
        while ($posts_result_rows = $posts_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $its_id = $posts_result_rows["userid"];
                        $its_title = $posts_result_rows['post_title']; 
                        $its_image = $posts_result_rows['file'];
                        $its_description = $posts_result_rows['post_description'];
        ?>
        <table border=0 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 >
            <tr>
                        <?php echo '<br>' . $its_title . ' <br>' . $its_description . '<br>'; ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo "users_data/users_posted_data/".$its_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $its_title; ?>" width="120" height="120"><hr>                   
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: In query this `user_posts.userid = image_data.client_id` but you are not selecting `user_posts` here `SELECT * FROM posts,image_data`

Answer (score 1):

Order by in descending order for getting latest row

```
 $posts = "select * from (SELECT * FROM posts,image_data WHERE userid='$user' AND posts.userid = image_data.client_id ORDER BY date_created DESC)temp group by userid ";
            $posts_result = $mysqli->query($posts);
```

Below mentioned SQL query is working fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a0e9/1

```
select * from 
(SELECT * FROM posts,image_data WHERE userid=1 
 AND posts.userid = image_data.client_id 
 ORDER BY date_created DESC)temp group by userid;
```

Comment: thats not what I meant because I am not trying to get the most updated post. here i am trying to show the user their uploaded posts but only limit the images to one per post. because each post can have up to 4 images.

Comment: @koroush : you want only image per post. Please specify... out of many images, which one you want? which field you use to identify latest image?

Comment: @koroush : code updated, please verify and let me know.

Comment: okay sorry about that but the column that gets the images is called file. Now, you for example as an user, can upload up to 4 images. but when you go to your own account on my website, there is a page for your recent posts which lists your posts. now on that page, you should only see one image/first uploaded image on each of your posts.

Comment: @koroush : i have updated the query. if `date_created` field is in table `image_data` then the code should give result as per your requirement.

Comment: I put your query in and this is the fatal error I got: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87965/discussion-between-koroush-and-seahawk).

Answer (score 0):

try adding LIMIT 1

```
$posts = "SELECT * FROM posts,image_data WHERE userid='$user' AND user_posts.userid = image_data.client_id ORDER BY date_created ASC LIMIT 1";
        $posts_result = $mysqli->query($posts);
```

Comment: I did that but what that does is that next time the user adds another post, the second post won't show up.

Comment: can you include your form so others can check it and knows what is the problem.

Comment: your approach is good. maybe there's a problem with the form or maybe in your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php           
        echo 'Your posts:<br><hr>'; 

        $posts = "SELECT * FROM posts,image_data WHERE userid='$user' AND user_posts.userid = image_data.client_id ORDER BY date_created ASC";
        $posts_result = $mysqli->query($posts);     
        while ($posts_result_rows = $posts_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $its_id = $posts_result_rows["userid"];
                        $its_title = $posts_result_rows['post_title']; 
                        $its_image = $posts_result_rows['file'];
                        $its_description =     $posts_result_rows['post_description'];

            echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 ><tr><td>"; 
            echo '<br>' . $its_title . ' <br>' . $its_description . '<br>';

        }
    ?>   
<img src="<?php echo "users_data/users_posted_data/".$its_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $its_title; ?>" width="120" height="120"><hr>                   
        </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: thanks but I get a undefined variable for $its_title.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $posts = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid='$user' ORDER BY date_created ASC";
    $posts_result = $mysqli->query($posts);     
    while ($posts_result_rows = $posts_result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $posts1 = "SELECT * FROM image_data WHERE client_id='$user' and file != '' ORDER BY image_id  DESC";
        $posts_result1 = $mysqli->query($posts1);   
        $posts_result_rows1 = $posts_result1->fetch_assoc()         

        $its_id = $posts_result_rows["userid"];
        $its_title = $posts_result_rows['post_title']; 
        $its_image = $posts_result_rows1['file'];
        $its_description =     $posts_result_rows['post_description'];

        ?>
    <table border=0 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo '<br>' . $its_title . ' <br>' . $its_description . '<br>'; ?>
                <img src="<?php echo "users_data/users_posted_data/".$its_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $its_title; ?>" width="120" height="120" />
                <hr>   
            </td>       
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    }
   ?>
```

The second image query write inside while loop for fetching only one image and also check file column is not empty. Idon't know what's your column name put your column name according your table structure.

Answer (score -1):

The important part is to add `limit 1`.

`SELECT * FROM posts,image_data WHERE userid='$user' AND user_posts.userid = image_data.client_id ORDER BY date_created ASC limit 1`